# sliding through a matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I am really new into Python and I have been trying to slide through a matrix. I am able to output a 2x2 block from a matrix but I wanna try sliding through the matrix but I can't get it right.

Code:

```
myMultidimensional = [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,10,15,20,25],[2,4,6,8,10]]
rows = 2
columns = 2
for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(columns):
        print(myMultidimensional[x][y], end=" ")
```

Output of the code: 1 2 5 10

Wanted output:

1 2 5 10

2 3 10 15 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
nrow = len(x)
ncol = len(x[0])

for i in range(nrow-1):
    for j in range(ncol-1):
        print(x[i][j], x[i][j+1], x[i+1][j], x[i+1][j+1])
```